# Append to a file, but always keep some text on the last line

Tags: python

I am working on this python file and I am appending information to it using user input. However, I have to be able to leave a bottom signature or a hard coded text without my append writting over it as soon as I re-run my program.

- Example:  `First Name \n Last Name \n sig \n`

  `First Name \n Last Name \n sig \n`

I am wanting

```
First Name \n
Last Name \n
First Name \n
Last Name \n
sig
```

Comment: While appending to a file is easy, having a string always at the bottom of a file isn't very straightforward. Please show some code that you have

Answer (score 0):

If you know the signature will always be a single line then you can read the full file into an array of lines, split it into data and sig, append to the data, recombine, and output to your file. Here's how you'd do it:

```
with open('myfile') as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()

data = lines[:-1]
sig = lines[-1]

# append lines to data
data.append('First Name')
data.append('Last Name')

# add the sig back on
data.append(sig)

with open('myfile', 'w') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(data))
```